# Count rows logic issue

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I'm trying to build a simple OOP login system for learning purpose.

This is the Auth class that I use for the register/login system.

```
<?php

require_once 'Database.class.php';

class Auth extends Database 
{
    const DATEFORMAT = 'd/m/Y';
    const TIMEFORMAT = 'H:i:s';

    public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database)
    {
        parent::__construct($host, $username, $password, $database);
        $this->connect();
        $this->setTable('users');
    }

    public function insert(array $data)
    {
        $username = $data['username'];
        $password = $data['password'];
        $repeat_password = $data['repeat_password'];
        $last_login = date(self::DATEFORMAT . ' ' . self::TIMEFORMAT);

        if ($password == $repeat_password)
        {
            $password = hash("sha256", $password);
            $stmt = $this->connection->prepare("INSERT INTO {$this->table} (username, password, last_login) VALUES(:username, :password, :last_login)");

            $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username, 
                                 ':password' => $password,
                                 ':last_login' => $last_login
                                 )
                           );
        }
        else
        {
            // do something
        }
    }

    public function select(array $data)
    {
        $username = $data['username'];
        $password = $data['password'];
        $password = hash("sha256", $password);

        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$this->table} WHERE username=:username AND password=:password LIMIT 1");

        $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username, 
                             ':password' => $password
                             )
                       );

        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

}
```

And this is the place where I use the class:

```
<?php

require_once 'Auth.class.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $auth = new Auth('localhost', 'root', '', 'oop');

    $user = $auth->select($_POST);

    if (count($user) === 0) {
        echo 'User not found!';
    }else{
        echo 'Hello, ' . ucfirst($user['username']);
    }
```

The problem is that even if the password is wrong or the username does not exists it doesn't display the error message "User not found!" so it seems that the condition where I specified that the count of the user variable should be greater than 0 doesn't work.

I tried looking for an alternative for the simple `count()` that I used but that didn't seem to help. I'm getting lost in the details of OOP and I think this is more of a logic problem than a syntax one.

Any ideas what I did wrong? Also, any constructive review of the code that I wrote is great to read. :)

Comment: You can use `var_dump` to see what's inside `$user` after you call the `select`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with OOP.  Ask yourself, *what* you want to count here? Then replace the condition with just `if ($user)`. While regarding the review, you may find this article interesting, [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Comment: @PierreDuc using var_dump returns `bool(false)`

Comment: @YourCommonSense Awesome read! Also checking _(The only proper) PDO tutorial_. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fetch fails, it returns FALSE. So you end up counting FALSE on fetch failure.

Since FALSE is not a countable or an array the function will return 1.

[count return values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php#refsect1-function.count-returnvalues)

To solve this, you can adjust your condition:

```
if (!$user)
```